# Use a property within an ItemsSource object as the property to display

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm, datagrid

I would like to bind a list of ViewModels to a `DataGrid` and then use a property on the ViewModel to display in the contents of the `DataGrid`.

Suppose I have the following ViewModel:

```
public class TableWrapperViewModel
{
    public object SourceTable { get; set; }     //An unknown type, auto generate the columns.
    public bool HasBeenDealtWith { get; set; }  //Used to control the row style.
}
```

In the View I have a `DataGrid` bound to an `ObservableCollection<TableWrapperViewModel> Tables`:

```
<DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding Tables}">
    <DataGrid.RowStyle>
        <Style TargetType="DataGridRow">
            <Style.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding HasBeenDealtWith}" Value="True">
                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="#BCFF77"/>
                </DataTrigger>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding HasBeenDealtWith}" Value="False">
                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="#FF7777"/>
                </DataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </DataGrid.RowStyle>
</DataGrid>
```

The result can be seen below. The rows are highlighted but the `SourceTable` is shown as a single column (as expected).
[image: Rows are highlighted but the SourceTable is shown in a single column.]

Is there a way I could display only the `SourceTable` property in the `DataGrid` whilst maintaining access to `HasBeenDealtWith` for styling purposes? The `DataGrid` must be able to generate the columns dynamically for the `SouceTable` object.

The result should look like the following but with the highlighting still in place:
[image: Resulting view]

Comment: Does the `[Display(AutoGenerateField = false)]` Attribute do any good in this?

Comment: Adding that attribute doesn't appear to do anything. I suspect if it did hide `HasBeenDealtWith`, I would still be left with the same issue of the `SourceTable` not being split into three separate columns (`SomeID`, `SomeProperty` and `SomethingElse`).

Comment: I meant add this Attribute to the `HasBeenDealtWith` property so that it would be marked as not to be an auto generated column, but it was just a wild guess.

Comment: I did that but it seems to be ignored. The resulting view after adding the attribute to `HasBeenDealtWith` is exactly as it was before.

Comment: I think you would need to have two nested ItemsControls to achieve your goal. One which creates an item for each `TableWrapperViewModel` and another "inner" ItemControl which creates an item for each property of your source table. This will require the use of some kind of `DataTemplate`s. In my opinion, what you want can not be accomplished with a single `DataGrid`.